# What is better for 64-bit Windows OS? XAMPP or WAMP

Tags: lamp

Does WAMP offer native 64-bit components (Apache, MySQL, PHP)?
XAMPP unfortunately have 32-bit binaries.

If i need my web applications to scale in terms of memory usage, would it make more sense to use WAMP instead?

Comment: Hi Fyi - Xampp has recently released 64bit installations late Feb 2019. See https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in shorts.

If You expect to use by one PHP more thah 2 - 3 Gb RAM

or DB can get advantage from huge ammount of memory.

But, IMHO bundled stacks useful for simple start or testing. It simplify components instalation and integration. You can easy change this stacks on go. And in production like to integrate desired components manually.

For example:

- WAMP include MySQL (original, maintained by Oracle)
- XAMPP include MariaDB (one of forks of MySQL, maintained by MariaDB Foundation)